# Google Chrome uncaught javascript exception

Tags: javascript, exception, google-chrome

This error does not happen in Firefox 4.0 or Internet Explorer 8+.

I create a new empty tab, and open console (Ctrl+Shift+I and then Esc) and paste the following codes:

```
var cnt = 0;
(function() {document.body.innerHTML = cnt;window.setTimeout(arguments.callee,100);})();

(function(){cnt++;window.setTimeout(arguments.callee,0);})();
```

Sometimes there is an error at this point but not always.

After this I paste more:

```
(function(){cnt++;window.setTimeout(arguments.callee,0);})();
```

After ~30sec I get any of these errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

The question: what is the problem? How can I solve this?

**UPDATE:**

This error happens when I switch between my opened tabs, but also randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `chrome://newtab` expects certain elements to be there (for JavaScript purposes) but you're wiping them out by using `document.body.innerHTML`. You could inject an element to use for your output instead, something like this should work:

```
var cnt = 0;
document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="abcd">...</div>' + document.body.innerHTML;

(function(){
    document.getElementById('abcd').innerHTML=cnt;
    window.setTimeout(arguments.callee,100);
})();

(function(){ cnt++;window.setTimeout(arguments.callee,0); })();
```